# is the torus homeomorphic to a piece of cylinder surface in the quotient?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, quotient-spaces

Considering over $X=S^1\times\mathbb R$, with the usual induced topology  and the equivalence relation 
$(u,t )R(u',t')$ if and only if $u'=\pm u, t-t' \in \mathbb Z$.

> Tell if $(X/R,\epsilon_2/R)$  is T2, connected compact and homeomorphic to the torus $S^1\times S^1$

any idea

Answer (score 0):

Being the first space $S^1$, the quotient defined by $R$ makes it $\mathbb{RP1}$ which is isomorphic to $S^1$ itself. In the second coordinate you have the exact definition of $S^1$ so your quotient space is actually isomorphic to a torus. Everything else can be answered from here.

Comment: Thanks for helping, what is RP1 and why is it isomorphic to $S^1$?

Comment: I saw is something called the real projective space but I don't see how it could be isomorplic to a circle

Comment: This answer is wrong, because the relation is not simply the product of two relations, one on each factor.

Comment: If I think of this geometrically I also get a rectangle with opposite sides identified so if you could develop your ideas further it would help @SteveD

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver The real projective line is the quotient of $S^1$ by $u \sim -u$ so it gives, let's say, the half upper semicircle. But, if you associate to every point in the hemisphere a line through the origin, you get exactly the set of all lines trough the origin which in turn is $S^1$ again. You can think of this anallitically by setting $S^1=\{ x^2+y^2=1\}$ and the quotient space as $S^1=\{ (x-1)^2+y^2=1\}$

Comment: @SteveD Now that I went over the question again I can see it is stated according to a pair, and there is some $\varepsilon_2$ involved there that I'm not so sure what means. Anyhow, my answer only is in regards to the quotient space $X$ so it could be wrong. I'm sorry I wasn't careful enough while reading... I'm a bit distracted a great deal of the time lol